# Use xml as data source in birt report programmatically

Tags: java, reporting, birt

I'm new in birt and I am trying to use xml as data source, but I don't get it works. 
I don't know if it's necessary specified more data, but I don't found any domentation that specify what is necessary to specify for using xml as data source.

I use with next code:

### Method to specify source and dataset

```
/** Set data source */ 
void buildDataSource() throws SemanticException {
    OdaDataSourceHandle dsHandle = this.efactory.newOdaDataSource("Data Source", "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml");
    dsHandle.setProperty("FILELIST", "http://localhost:8080/BirtIntegrationImproved/ReportXmlDatasource/books.xml");

    this.design.getDataSources().add(dsHandle);
}

/** Set data set */     
void buildDataSet() throws SemanticException {
    OdaDataSetHandle dsHandle = this.efactory.newOdaDataSet("ds","org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.dataSet");
    dsHandle.setDataSource("Data Source");

    this.design.getDataSets().add(dsHandle); 
}
```

### Creation of table where data source is used

```
/** List of columns */    
ArrayList<String> cols = new ArrayList<String>();       
cols.add("id");
cols.add("author");
cols.add("title");
cols.add("genre");
cols.add("price");

buildDataSource();
buildDataSet();

TableHandle table = this.efactory.newTableItem("table", cols.size());

table.setWidth("100%");
table.setDataSet(this.design.findDataSet("ds"));
PropertyHandle computedSet = table.getColumnBindings();
ComputedColumn  cs1 = null;

for( int i=0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
    cs1 = StructureFactory.createComputedColumn();
    cs1.setName((String)cols.get(i));
    cs1.setExpression("dataSetRow[\"" + (String)cols.get(i) + "\"]");
    computedSet.addItem(cs1);
}              

// table header
RowHandle tableheader = (RowHandle) table.getHeader().get(0);
for(int i=0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
    LabelHandle label1 = this.efactory.newLabel((String)cols.get(i)); 
    label1.setText((String)cols.get(i));
    CellHandle cell = (CellHandle) tableheader.getCells().get(i);
    cell.getContent().add(label1);
} 

// table detail
RowHandle tabledetail = (RowHandle) table.getDetail().get(0);

for(int i=0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
    CellHandle cell = (CellHandle) tabledetail.getCells().get(i);
    DataItemHandle data = this.efactory.newDataItem("data_"+(String)cols.get(i));
    data.setResultSetColumn((String)cols.get(i));
    System.out.println("ResultSetColumn: " + data.getResultSetColumn());
    cell.getContent( ).add(data);
```

}

do someone knows what's wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To get data from xml as data source, you need to follow the steps below:
1. Save your xml with data populated to any path on your system.
2. Map this path to the data source.
3. Map the fields from the xml you want to see on your report in the data set.

The report can now be designed in the same way as you would if you were retrieving the data from a database.